# How to use javascript/jquery/css3 to make responsive flex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

My html and css look like this

```css
.section {
  display: flex;
}
.section > .zone:first-child {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="zone">
    [content]
  </div>
  <div class="zone">
    [content]
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what I want, that is it is two columns, and the width of first column is maximized and width of second column is minimized. The problem though is, if there is fixed width (or min width) elements in the `[content]` parts. What happens is the flex ignores that, and just overlaps the zones on top of each other, when the window width gets small enough. I want it so that, right before they start to overlap (say at window width `X`), it should remove the flex, so that the zones stack vertically with maximum width.

But if the window width should expand again (going past window width `X`), then it should return back to display:flex.

Does anyone know how I can use jquery to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: With just CSS, you should be able to do that with [flex-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) and media queries.

Comment: But how does flex detect fixed width elements?

Comment: if you apply `flex-wrap: wrap` on `section` and with media queries apply `flex-grow: 1` on `zone` when the device width hits `x` width. flex-wrap stacks it, and flex-grow fills the space of the container

Comment: The problem is `x` is not known, its all dynamic.

Comment: So write that CSS and append it to head via jQuery.

Comment: How would I even find `X`? I am not given it, I would need jquery to calculate it, that's the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122784/discussion-between-ankith-amtange-and-omega).

Comment: Can you create a better demo where the overlap is happening? Here's a [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/xk2v0g36/) using `wrap`, even if you increase the fixed width element it will stack..

Comment: Thanks, the flex-wrap:row wrap works pretty good, but it needs one zone to have a fixed width. Is there a way I can have all zones, **after** it gets wrapped from flex-wrap, to change width to 100%?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to **imitate responsiveness without having to write any breakpoints.** So instead of specifying them explicitly, you could create two variables to determine the screen size.

[Fiddle Example for `flex-wrap method`.](https://jsfiddle.net/thelessergeek/zhhpv88w/)

The `.zones` usually stack, if their **sum width** is greater than the **container width.** This is basic Wrap. **That sum-width is your X.** When its greater than the container width, your fixed size elements start to overlap.

> Add the `outerWidth()` of each `.zone` and assign any screen size below or equal to this as a small device.

```
xWidth = zone1 + zone2;
var smallDevice = windowWidth <= xWidth;
```

**Flex usually distributes the space inside a container and so if wrapped, elements do not stack when there is enough space.** Using that, we determine the widest `.zone` and combine it with the **xWidth** to create another breakpoint condition. This is helpful when scaling back from a small view-port. Cos scaling back, all stacked elements have 100% width. More or less.

> A size wider than the the largest `.zone` **AND** the `xWidth` could be a large device.

```
dynamicBreakpoint = Math.max(zone1, zone2); // determine the greater zone
var largeDevice = windowWidth > xWidth && windowWidth > dynamicBreakpoint;
```

You could then append/remove a stylesheet into/from the document head based on a window `resize()` event. Just remember to check if the stylesheet is already added.

```
stylesheet = "<style type='text/css' id='checkCSS'>" + styles + "</style>";

if (checkCSS === 0 && smallDevice) {
  $(stylesheet).appendTo('head');
} else if (checkCSS === 1 && largeDevice) {
  $('#checkCSS').remove();
}
```

You could also use an array or a map method if working with more than two elements. Just a thought on how it could be done. There could **definitely** be a better method.

Comment: It is not fixed 560 in my case, its dynamic value which would have to be calculated manually.